# you can't concatenate a string with a function call in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reference an index in an array, but gameObjects[1] comes back as undefined. gameObjects is an array of objects.

```
var gameObjects = [enemy,treasure];


var mysteryBlock = {
name: "Mystery Block",
output:"produces " + gameObjects[1] 

}

var enemy = {
output: "an enemy"
}

var treasure = {

  output: "a treasure"

}

console.log("your mystery cube " + mysteryBlock.output)
```

comes back as undefined.

Comment: Maybe you meant `output: "produces " + gameObjects[1].output`

Comment: And where is the function call you're referring to in the title?

Answer (score 1):

You should define `enemy` and `treasure` before you use them. It's not working because you need to reference the `output` property of the object:

```
var enemy = {
  output: "an enemy"
}

var treasure = {
  output: "a treasure"
}

var gameObjects = [enemy,treasure];


var mysteryBlock = {
  name: "Mystery Block",
  output:"produces " + gameObjects[1].output 
}


console.log("your mystery cube " + mysteryBlock.output);
```

[Here it is working](http://codepen.io/pabs123/pen/LWNyOa)

Comment: Variable hoisting. We can use them even before we define them

Comment: I changed my wording to say he should define them first. I realize it works, I'm just suggesting there's no reason not to do it in order

Comment: Sorry, i realized that variable hoisting does not work in this case. The order is necessary. JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations.

Answer (score 1):

The `gameObjects` variable is an array of objects and looks like:

```
[{
  "output": "an enemy"
},
{
  "output": "a treasure"
}]
```

Calling it by using `gameObjects[1]`, you will receive an object. To get the result, you have to **specify the `key`**, which in your case will be `output`.

```js
var enemy = {
  output: "an enemy"
}

var treasure = {
  output: "a treasure"
}

var gameObjects = [enemy, treasure];

var mysteryBlock = {
  name: "Mystery Block",
  output: "produces " + gameObjects[1].output //mentioned line of code
}

console.log("your mystery cube " + mysteryBlock.output)
```